# Как изменить работу виджета CListView в Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Уже час копаюсь в коде виджета CListView и так и не разберусь, как его изменить так, чтобы
присвоить элементам списка свои классы. четным один -- нечетным второй класс. Как вообще [это](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#renderItems-detail) работает? В переменную data сохраняются данные из dataProvider, потом тут же она переопределяется... я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JpxLg/ вот так вас не устроит случайно ?

Comment: да было бы здорово, но мне кажется ie наплевать на такие селекторы

Comment: modernizr используйте, fallback делайте как здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JpxLg/1/ (у jQuery, тоже такой селектор есть)

Comment: точно, спасибо. я бы и не догадался. но теперь нет нужды использовать js

Answer (score 1):

всё, разобрался

```
foreach($data as $i=>$item)
{
    $data=$this->viewData;
    $data['index']=$i;
    $data['data']=$item;
    $data['widget']=$this;
    $owner->renderFile($viewFile,$data);
    if($j++ < $n-1)
        echo $this->separator;
}
```

тут данные передаются в виджет в виде переменных с именами, соответствующими ключам массива $data. собственно в $data['data'], которая в файле $viewFile содержатся данные из dataProvider. так же в файле $viewFile доступны переменные $widget и $index, которую мы собственно и можем использовать для сортировки элементов списка

```
<div class="view <?php echo $index%2?'right':'left' ?>">
  тут выводятся данные элемента списка
</div>
```

меня смутило что $data, которая используется в foreach, переопределяется внутри него. по идее, после первой же итерации обходить уже нечего. да не тут то было

```
<?php

$data = array(1,2,3,4);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.' ';
    $data = 'null';
}
echo $data;

?>
```

выведет "`1 2 3 4 null`".
то есть $data приняла значение 'null' только после окончания foreach!

Answer (score 0):

> четным один -- нечетным второй класс

Насколько я помню, в этом виджете такой возможности нет. Как вариант, попробуйте реализовать это при помощи JS, а если Вы используете в своём проекте библиотеку jQuery, то проще будет воспользоваться [её возможностями](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B).

> как вообще это работает?

Листинг метода приведён под его описанием в [Вашей ссылке](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#renderItems-detail) (Source Code). Что Вас конкретно интересует? Где Вы собираетесь применить этот метод?

> в переменную data сохраняются данные
> из dataProvider, потом тут же она
> переопределяется

Методы render() или renderPartitial() сами по себе не вносят в передаваемые во вьюшки переменные никаких изменений. Если у Вас что-то переопределяется, то проверяйте свой код.

Comment: >>Насколько я помню, в этом виджете такой возможности нет.
в том то и дело, что нет. я как раз хотел написать свой класс расширяющий этот виджет.
>>Методы render() или renderPartitial() сами по себе не вносят в передаваемые во вьюшки переменные никаких изменений.
это тоже понятно. не понятно что содержит переменная $data и для чего она

Comment: Напишите функцию определения CSS-стилей в зависимости от чётного/нечётного порядкового номера пункта в списке, воспользовавшись тем же примером с jQuery. Засуньте её в параметр htmlOptions как анонимную функцию, и будет она вам вызываться всякий раз при вызове CListView. И нет необходимости в написании всяких классов. А по поводу $data - под каким именем её во view отправите, под таким и используйте :)
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/ru/post.display - обратите внимание на параметр 'model' в функции render(). Во view к ней можно будет обратиться как к $model